# how to get tornadoredis listen value

Tags: redis, tornado, coroutine

I want to write a chat demo with tornado and redis.  I use redis subscribe , but what I wrote is not work .   when I run the code , iterm output

```
listening 8000
GroupChat here
getMsg here
None
None
```

And I PUBLISH testc helloword in redis-cli, iterm output:

```
[I 150401 18:30:57 web:1825] 304 GET /groupchat?key=testc (127.0.0.1) 2.40ms
Message(kind=u'message', channel=u'testc', body=u'helloword', pattern=u'testc')
```

I just want to get the Message in GroupChat.get , but I get None. anyone help me?

GroupChat code is here :

```
class GroupChat(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self):
        print 'GroupChat here'
        self.c = tornadoredis.Client(host=CONFIG['REDIS_HOST'], port=CONFIG['REDIS_PORT'], password=CONFIG['REDIS_AUTH'])
        self.channelMsgModel = channelMsgModel(self.c)
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        try:
            key = self.get_argument('key')
            info = yield self.channelMsgModel.getMsg(key)
            print info
            self.finish(info)
        except Exception, e:
            print e
        pass
```

channelMsgModel code is here :

import tornado.gen

```
class channelMsgModel :
    timeout = 10
    def __init__(self, redisobj):
        self.redisobj = redisobj

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def getMsg(self, key):
        print 'getMsg here'
        yield tornado.gen.Task(self.redisobj.subscribe, key)
        info = self.redisobj.listen(self.on_message)
        print info
        raise tornado.gen.Return(info)

    def on_message(self, msg):
        if (msg.kind == 'message'):
            print msg
            return msg
        elif (msg.kind == 'unsubscribe'):
            self.redisobj.disconnect()
            # raise tornado.gen.Return(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [toro.Queue](http://toro.readthedocs.org/en/stable/classes.html#queue) (which will be included in Tornado itself in the upcoming version 4.2):

```
class channelMsgModel:
    def __init__(self, redisobj):
        self.redisobj = redisobj
        self.queue = toro.Queue()

    @gen.coroutine
    def getMsg(self, key):
        yield gen.Task(self.redisobj.subscribe, key)
        self.redisobj.listen(self.on_message)
        info = yield self.queue.get()
        raise tornado.gen.Return(info)

    def on_message(self, msg):
        if (msg.kind == 'message'):
            self.queue.put_nowait(msg)
        elif (msg.kind == 'unsubscribe'):
            self.redisobj.disconnect()
```